# How to plot this data with errorBar

Tags: plotting, warning-messages, data, logarithmic-scale

```
B = ErrorListLogPlot[{{{13.952, 364.7}, ErrorBar[36.4]}, {{19.13, 309.11}, ErrorBar[30.9]}, {{21, 294.159}, ErrorBar[29.4]}, {{26.2635, 237.26}, ErrorBar[23.7]}, 
    {{29.0713, 191.367}, ErrorBar[19.1]}, {{32.959, 151.82}, ErrorBar[15.1]}, {{37.2786, 118.47}, ErrorBar[11.8]}, {{42.246, 86.529}, ErrorBar[8.6]}, 
    {{46.1339, 67.5217}, ErrorBar[6.7]}, {{48.9417, 39.7778}, ErrorBar[3.9]}, {{52.6134, 32.0836}, ErrorBar[3.2]}, {{54.7732, 24.2215}, ErrorBar[2.4]}, 
    {{58.2289, 14.0352}, ErrorBar[1.4]}, {{62.7646, 6.13975}, ErrorBar[0.6]}, {{67.5162, 3.617}, ErrorBar[0.36]}, {{71.8359, 2.20246}, ErrorBar[0.22]}, 
    {{78.0994, 1.92956}, ErrorBar[0.19]}, {{81.987, 1.36348}, ErrorBar[0.13]}, Null, {{88.4665, 1.34112}, ErrorBar[0.13]}, Null, 
    {{95.162, 1.34112}, ErrorBar[0.13]}, {{104.665, 1.36348}, ErrorBar[0.13]}}, {{115.464, 0.979543}, ErrorBar[0.09]}, {{125.616, 0.777114}, ErrorBar[0.55]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{20, 70}, {0.1, 300}}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"θcm", "dσ/dΩ(mb)"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Medium], 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[{"(dσ/dΩ)Exp"}, Center], PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Medium]]
```

this what is shown it is empty of point
LegendedGraphics[{{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}}, {DisplayFunction -> Identity, GridLines -> {None, None}, DisplayFunction -> Identity, DisplayFunction -> Identity,
DisplayFunction -> Identity, PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, AxesOrigin -> {10.35, -2.245020465669194},
PlotRange -> {{10, 80}, {-2.3025850929940455, Log[10000]}}, PlotRangeClipping -> True, ImagePadding -> All, DisplayFunction -> Identity,
AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio^(-1), Axes -> {True, True}, AxesLabel -> {None, None}, AxesOrigin -> {10.35, -2.245020465669194}, DisplayFunction :> Identity,
Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, True}}, FrameLabel -> {{"d[Sigma]/d[CapitalOmega", None}, {"[Theta]cm", None}},
FrameTicks -> {{Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}], Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Log, Exp}]}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, GridLines -> {None, None},
GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.5, 0.4]], LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Medium],
Method -> {"CoordinatesToolOptions" -> {"DisplayFunction" -> ({(Identity[#1] & )[#1[[1]]], (Exp[#1] & )[#1[[2]]]} & ),
"CopiedValueFunction" -> ({(Identity[#1] & )[#1[[1]]], (Exp[#1] & )[#1[[2]]]} & )}}, PlotRange -> {{10, 80}, {-2.3025850929940455, Log[10000]}},
PlotRangeClipping -> True, PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, Ticks -> {Automatic, Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}]}}],
Placed[Unevaluated[PointLegend[{Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334], AbsoluteThickness[1.6], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]],
Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334], AbsoluteThickness[1.6], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334], AbsoluteThickness[1.6],
RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334], AbsoluteThickness[1.6], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]],
Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334], AbsoluteThickness[1.6], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334], AbsoluteThickness[1.6],
RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334], AbsoluteThickness[1.6], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]],
Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334], AbsoluteThickness[1.6], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334], AbsoluteThickness[1.6],
RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334], AbsoluteThickness[1.6], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]],
Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334], AbsoluteThickness[1.6], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334], AbsoluteThickness[1.6],
RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334], AbsoluteThickness[1.6], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]],
Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334], AbsoluteThickness[1.6], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334], AbsoluteThickness[1.6],
RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334], AbsoluteThickness[1.6], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]],
Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334], AbsoluteThickness[1.6], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334], AbsoluteThickness[1.6],
RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334], AbsoluteThickness[1.6], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]],
Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334], AbsoluteThickness[1.6], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334], AbsoluteThickness[1.6],
RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334], AbsoluteThickness[1.6], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]],
Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334], AbsoluteThickness[1.6], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]}, {"(d[Sigma]/d[CapitalOmega])Exp"}, LegendMarkers -> {{False, Automatic}},
Joined -> {False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
False, False}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Medium], LegendLayout -> {"Column", {Automatic, 5}}]], Center, Identity]]

Comment: V12 docs say "As of Version 12, ErrorListPlot has been superseded by ListPlot." but seems to have no further information. I tried `ellp[{{x_,y_},ErrorBar[dy_]}]:={{x,y},{x,y+dy/2},{x,y-dy/2}};
ErrorListLogPlot[ellpdata_,ellpopts__]:=ListLogPlot[Map[ellp,ellpdata],ellpopts];
ErrorListLogPlot[..yourexample..]` without Null and with only one data set. Error bars are so small with your data that changing y plot range to `{100,300}` makes the individual points visible. Perhaps you or others can make this better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = {{{13.952, 364.7}, ErrorBar[36.4]}, {{19.13, 309.11}, 
    ErrorBar[30.9]}, {{21, 294.159}, 
    ErrorBar[29.4]}, {{26.2635, 237.26}, 
    ErrorBar[23.7]}, {{29.0713, 191.367}, 
    ErrorBar[19.1]}, {{32.959, 151.82}, 
    ErrorBar[15.1]}, {{37.2786, 118.47}, 
    ErrorBar[11.8]}, {{42.246, 86.529}, 
    ErrorBar[8.6]}, {{46.1339, 67.5217}, 
    ErrorBar[6.7]}, {{48.9417, 39.7778}, 
    ErrorBar[3.9]}, {{52.6134, 32.0836}, 
    ErrorBar[3.2]}, {{54.7732, 24.2215}, 
    ErrorBar[2.4]}, {{58.2289, 14.0352}, 
    ErrorBar[1.4]}, {{62.7646, 6.13975}, 
    ErrorBar[0.6]}, {{67.5162, 3.617}, 
    ErrorBar[0.36]}, {{71.8359, 2.20246}, 
    ErrorBar[0.22]}, {{78.0994, 1.92956}, 
    ErrorBar[0.19]}, {{81.987, 1.36348}, ErrorBar[0.13]}, 
   Null, {{88.4665, 1.34112}, ErrorBar[0.13]}, 
   Null, {{95.162, 1.34112}, ErrorBar[0.13]}, {{104.665, 1.36348}, 
    ErrorBar[0.13]}, {{115.464, 0.979543}, 
    ErrorBar[0.09]}, {{125.616, 0.777114}, ErrorBar[0.55]}};

data2 = data /.
   {Null :> 
     Nothing, {{x_, y_}, ErrorBar[err_]} :> {x, Around[y, err]}};

B = ListLogPlot[data2,
  PlotRange -> {{20, 70}, {0.1, 300}},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {"θcm", "dσ/dΩ(mb)"},
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Medium],
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{"(dσ/dΩ)Exp"}, Center],
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Medium]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** To see all of the data

```
B2 = ListLogPlot[data2,
  PlotRange -> All,
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {"θcm", "dσ/dΩ(mb)"},
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Medium],
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{"(dσ/dΩ)Exp"}, {.7, .65}],
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Medium]]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you ,, It was helpfull ,, every thing work correct but the curve is empty

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you want the data points connected, use the option `Joined -> True`